# Make AWS IoT rule trigger Lambda function using specific alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm making updates to a Lambda function that is triggered by an AWS IoT rule. In order to be able to quickly revert, use weighted aliases, etc., I would like to update this rule to point to a specific `production` alias of the function so that I can make updates to `$LATEST` and test them out. If everything goes well, I would make a new version and make the `production` alias point to that.

But when I try to update the action to trigger the alias instead of $LATEST, I'm only given choices of *versions* or `$LATEST`:

[image: Can only select a specific version or latest, not an alias]

Any ideas? Google yields nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the trigger on the other side. I had to add the trigger to the `production` alias and then delete the link to default/$LATEST under the Lambda function itself.

Answer (score 0):

As far aas I know:
You can define an alias via the CLI. It is not possible via the web interface I think.

Have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/lambda-rule-action.html).

```
{
    "topicRulePayload": {
        "sql": "SELECT * FROM 'some/topic'",
        "ruleDisabled": false,
        "awsIotSqlVersion": "2016-03-23",
        "actions": [
            {
                "lambda": {
                    "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:${topic()}"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can type: `"functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:${topic():MY_ALIAS}"`

But you have to set this up via the CLI.